# Why am I getting an error in Prolog when trying out conc?

Tags: prolog

If I'm trying out next query in Prolog, I'm getting an error...

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 6.4.1)
Copyright (c) 1990-2013 University of Amsterdam, VU Amsterdam
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software,
and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Please visit http://www.swi-prolog.org for details.

?- conc([a,b], [c,d], [a,b,c,d] ).
ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: conc/3 (DWIM could not correct goal)
```

Is this because I'm not loading in a seperate file with facts and rules? Because that seems strange. Next query for instance does work:

```
?- member(apple, [apple, broccoli, crackers]).
true .
```

Comment: use append instead of conc

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `conc` was a built in predicate for SWI Prolog?

Comment: I'm currently reading Bratko's "Prolog Programming for Artificial Intelligence" and it seemed to me that conc was something built in. Maybe I'll have to re-read the part about conc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using SWI-Prolog as the interpreter and there is no built-in predicate `conc` shipped with it. You can have a look at **[append/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append/3)** (which is also a predicate from the **[list library](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=lists)**, but note that in SWI this library is autoloaded while it is not always true in other implementation, eg see Yap, so you'd better use **[use_module](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=use_module/1)**).

Are you studying Prolog from Bratko's "Prolog Programming for Artificial Intelligence"?
(If the answer is yes, you'd better try to implement those predicate by yourself :))

Comment: Yes, I am studying Bratko's book. Why isn't that mentioned in the book? Anyway, thx!

Comment: Because the point of the book is to construct your predicates throughout each chapter and reuse them later on. It is a good excercise to build the book versions and compare them against the libs of swi and yap : )

Comment: Ok, managed to get conc and member working by building them myself. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

See the [FAQ](http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/ToplevelMode.html). You can only enter *queries* at the toplevel prompt.